# How to add Horizontal scrolling in console inspector for chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, google-chrome

I'm getting the response from the database and if the data is to long I couldn't able to see the remaining data so how can I add the horizontal scroll in the console inspector in chrome

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - click on this 3 dots
[screenshot of chrome's console inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87If1.png)

Step 2 - Select dock to right or dock to left according to your preference